# How can i implement a form-based authentication in JBoss EAP 7.0.7?

Tags: authentication, jboss-eap-7, securitydomain

Hi I am new to JBoss EAP 7.0.7! I am trying to deploy an ear file which was previously deployed in JBoss EAP 6.3. In the login page, it uses a form-based authentication with j_security_check. In my `jboss-web.xml`, the security-domain is set with a valve with class-name `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn`.

The application works in JBoss EAP 6.3. I tried to debug it and noticed that it invokes a method from `SingleSignOn` class as well as `FormAuthenticator` class.

The problem is that the application does not work when deployed in JBoss EAP 7.0.7. And when I debug it, it does not seem to invoke the SingleSignOn and `FormAuthenticator` methods. So how can I apply the same form-based authentication in JBoss EAP 7.0.7. (Note: I checked in the documentation and found out about the RH-SSO(Red Hat Single Sign On) but I cant download it.

Thanks in advance for your answer/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do the web applications bundled in your EAR require single sign-on?  If not, you don't need to mess with single sign-on.

All you need is to configure a security domain, using one of the methods outlines in the documentation:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_identity_management/

Using form authentication is just a matter of configuring web.xml and jboss-web.xml to use your security-domain name (i.e. realm-name).  See: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_identity_management/#configuring_an_application_to_use_a_security_domain_with_certificate_based_authentication

While this example demonstrates certificate-based authentication - to configure form authentication, just use FORM instead, and add the requisite  and  elements (as defined by the servlet specification).